# Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было Вашим/Вашем

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Похоже на то, что, так как это тв. п., нужен и-вариант.

> Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было Вашим/Ваше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначно через *и*:

*Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было (как**и**м?) Вашим*.

Если в вопросе от существительного к прилагательному есть буква И, то в окончании будет либо И, либо Ы. Буквы Ы быть не может, поскольку буква идëт после буквы Ш.

Здесь, правда, верный вопрос не *каким*, а *чьим*, но суть вы поняли.

Comment: Максим, вы ответили по вариантам из шапки, а в цитате у Лео другие варианты. Именно они, думаю, интересуют Лео, так как он пишет о тв. падеже. То есть вопрос будет или *каким? (чьим?)*, или *какое? (чьё?)*.  Ваш**им** или Ваш**е**. (Кстати, вопрос здесь задаётся от глагола.)

Answer (score 2):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Рустам, до оценки ответа еще очень далеко. У меня есть **вопросы** не только к вам, но и ко всему обществу.  Начнем со **смысла**.

1. А в чем там **смысл**, о чем говорится в вопросе? Контекст неясен. Вот предложение: *Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было **Вашим/Ваше**.*

По теории (Розенталь) возможны **обе формы**, это стилистика. Есть **общие тенденции** при выборе формы (ориентация на постоянство признака, на стиль речи), но есть еще **частные** моменты, когда выбор делается почти **интуитивно,** по конкретному предложению.

Для этого надо хорошо понимать эту замысловатую фразу: **кто, когда и зачем** это говорит. А откуда оно возьмется, это понимание. Но это замечание к качеству вопроса и его автору.

**Второе замечание** касается местоименного прилагательное ***Ваш.*** Разряд по значению: притяжательное (чей?). По словарю у него **шесть** значений, надо выбирать **по ситуации**. И это тоже замечание к **качеству вопроса** и его автору.

2. В именных сказуемых связь слов **двунаправленная**: подлежащее, связка, именная часть.

**В общем случае** глагол ***быть*** определяет **падеж** именной части, а согласование **по числу и роду** делается с **подлежащим**.

Обычно именная часть стоит **в форме И.п.**, поэтому о тройственном союзе никто и не вспоминает. Но в принципе возможен вариант, когда ***быть*** задает Т.п. именной части: **быть чье?** (постоянство признака) и **быть чьим** (признак в текущий момент).

3. Что **имел в виду** автор, я не знаю. Надо было сразу ему сказать: приведите **контекст!**  Но никто и не подумал это сделать.  **А теперь что делать?**  Лучше бы этот вопрос закрыть и не вспоминать о нем больше никогда.  А Лео пусть задаст нам вопрос в **новой редакции**.

И еще замечание к вашим ответам: **информативная перегруженность!** В ответе должна быть информация, которая непосредственно касается решения **заданной проблемы**. Ничего лишнего, иначе главного не видно.

И сразу  – быка за рога! То есть **действовать**, не теряя времени, решительно и наверняка. Начинать ответ надо было **с выбора падежей**: грамматика, Розенталь, а дальше ваше обоснованное решение. Или лучше сначала решение, а потом обоснование. И чем короче ответ, тем лучше. **Пиши, сокращай** – принцип информативности.

Разбор  **[вопроса по этой теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476679/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC).**

Comment: Sharon, замечания понял. Постараюсь исправиться. Спасибо, что разобрали эту тему.

Comment: Прекрасно! Мне нравится ваше серьезное отношение к языку. Без этого в любом деле трудно добиться успеха))

Answer (score 1):

Попутку №1 я бы удалил, как неудачную, чтобы не вносить путаницы.

**Попытка №1**

*Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было Ваше.*

Вынужден согласится с Александром Стрельцом, что вопрос уместнее задавать от глагола. Приведу свои рассуждения. Сначала, я думал, что решение зависит от контекста.

Если субъект (лицо, к которому обращаются) - ед. число, то наиболее точным было бы определение **Вашим**.

*В связи с плохой успеваемостью ученика Васечкина учитель обратился к его матери с просьбой. "Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было Вашим. Не нужно идти на поводу у своих детей."* Решение (**было каким?)(было чьим?)** Вашим.

Если субъект - мн. ч., то **Ваше**.

*В связи с плохой успеваемостью ученика Васечкина учитель обратился к его родителям с просьбой. "Я хочу, чтоб любое решение, Вами принятое, было Ваше. Не нужно идти на поводу у своих детей."* Решение было **(чье?)** Ваше.

Затем, я обратил внимание на задаваемый мною вопрос, который задаётся для определения ед. ч. В нём присутствует глагол **было**.

**Попытка №2**

Я считаю, что возможно оба варианта: *Вашим* или *Ваше*. Об этом далее.
Это сложноподчиненное предложение, части которого соединяются союзом *чтоб*. Разберем предложение по составу. Главная часть - *Я хочу*. Нераспространенная.

*Я* - подлежащее, выраженное местоимением 1 л., ед. ч.
*хочу* - сказуемое (простое), выраженное глаголом.

Придаточная часть - *решение было Вашим/Ваше*. Распространенная. Начну с второстепенных членов.

*любое* - определение. Как член предложения оно выражено прилагательным. Согласуется с существительным (*решение*).

*Вами принятое* - причастный оборот. *Принятое* - причастие, страдательное, прош. вр. *Вами* - местоимение 2-о л., ед. ч.

*Решение* - подлежащее, выраженное существительным 3-о л., ср. р., ед. ч. Неодушевленное.

*Было Вашим/Ваше* - составное именное сказуемое (СИС). Разберем его подробно.

*Было* - вспомогательная часть (связка), выраженное глаголом несовершенного вида, прошедш. вр., изъявительного наклонения, 2-е лицо. Вид связки по значению - грамматическая.

*Ваше* - основная часть (именная), выраженная местоименным прилагательным 2-о л., ед. ч. Способ выражения именной части - полное прилагательное в **именительном** падеже.
Как местоимение, оно притяжательное, личное, указывающее на принадлежность 2-у л. ср. рода. Так как местоим. прил. зависит от глагола (а не от сущ.), то задаем от него вопрос. Было *(чье?) Ваше*. Падеж именительный.

*Вашим* - основная часть (именная), выраженная местоименным прилагательным 2-о л., ед. ч. Способ выражения именной части - полное прилагательное в **творительном** падеже.
Как местоимение, оно притяжательное, личное, указывающее на принадлежность 2-у л. ср. рода. Задаем вопрос от глагола. Было *(чьим?) Вашим*. Падеж творительный.

Так как местоименное прил. не является определением и не согласуется с сущ., то я считаю, что возможны 2 варианта написания. Хочу также заметить (мое наблюдение), что с глаголом оно согласуется, а глагол с местоим. прил. - нет.

В 1-й попытке я не обратил внимания, что *Ваше/Вашим* пишется с большой буквы. Невнимателен был.

**По поводу изменения смысла при изменении слова.** По моим ощущениям, смысл не изменяется, с контекстом или без. Возможно это связано из-за того, что эти слова не являются самостоятельным членом предложения, а входят в *СИС*. Смысл мог быть в падежах. Творительный указывает на *"инструмент"* действия. Именительный, кажется, указывает на *"предмет"* действия. Ни инструмента, ни предмета в предложении я не нахожу. Хотя... Если и есть какой-то смысл, то он 1: *местоим. прил. указывает на принадлежность предмета субъекту действия.*

*Решение было (чьим?)Вашим / (чье?)Ваше*.

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5

Comment: А какая разница, Ваше или Вашим? Смыл меняется? А какой здесь смысл? Как он меняется?  Можно обозначить смысл коротко, одним предложением?

Comment: Рустам, выбор зависит не от числа или количества субъектов, а от падежа. Чьим? Вашим. Чьё? Ваше.

Comment: *Александр*, может это вообще не творительный, а винительный падеж? Так как определение (Ваш) согласуется с определяемым существительным (решение) в падеже и числе, то существительное тут не может быть творительным (решение - это не творит. п.).
*Sharon*, мне почему-то показалось, что **Вашим** звучит как-то странно. В общем-то, **твоим** тоже странно. Согласен, что мой ответ - неудачный.

Comment: Рустам, падежом здесь управляет не существительное, а глагол: *был мой, стал твой; был моим, стал твоим; было ваше, стало наше; было вашим, стало нашим*.  И так, и так можно.

Comment: 1) Притяжательные местоимения согласуются с существительными по числу и падежу. Если это твор. п., то пишется **Вашим решением**.
2) Если глагол управляет определением, то он переходный. Т.е, действие направленно на предмет. *Я хочу, чтобы было Ваше решение.* Это либо винительный падеж, либо родительный. 
3) *Было* управляет существительным (*решением*). Если это непереходный глагол, то он мог бы отвечать на вопросы косвенных падежей. А в данном примере это не так! Смотрите. В русском языке у определения нет фиксированного места - ставим его на др. место. **Я хочу, чтобы было Вашим решение**

Comment: В 3-м пункте неправильно написал. **Я хочу, чтоб Вашим решение было.** Либо **Я хочу, чтоб решение Вашим было.** Придаточную часть я убрал: она не изменяет смысла предложения.

Comment: Рустам, вы окончательно всё перемешали...

Comment: А я вот суть не поняла. Был задан вопрос, было дано два полезных ответа, один из ответов помог автору разобраться в проблеме. Как помог – трудно сказать. Возможная ошибка в заголовке (ВашЕм) так и осталась.  У меня такое впечатление, что никто и ничего не понял. Где же КАЧЕСТВО темы?  Так мы РАБОТАЕМ? На мой вопрос  о смысле  никто и внимания не обратил.  И что я должна подумать?.. Минусовать ответ не хочется, а надо бы.

Comment: Sharon, **извините меня**! Я вчера допустил ошибку, пытался исправить - не получилось. И не мог объяснить, не знал, как изменяется смысл, не мог объяснить. Мне неловко было, что мой ответ (1 попытка) была неудачный. Ночью начал думать. К утру появились новые мысли. Добавил их в конец ответа. Поправьте, пожалуйста, если есть замечания.

Comment: Рустам, мой комментарий в поле ответа.