# Выбор творительного или именительного падежа в составном именном сказуемом

Tags: согласование, падежи, управление, сказуемые

Вот текст:

*Выбирая  правильную точку зрения, не стоит во всем полагаться на мнения других людей. Пусть это будет **вашим мнением/ваше мнение.***

**Какой падеж** нужно выбрать и почему?

Answer (score 2):

*Выбирая  правильную точку зрения, не стоит во всем полагаться на мнения других людей. Пусть это будет  **вашим мнением/ваше мнение.***

1. Существительное и прилагательное в функции именной части составного сказуемого могут стоять как в форме **именительного**, так и в форме **творительного** падежа.
2. **При выборе Т.п**. надо учитывать **двунаправленную** связь существительного/прилагательного с подлежащим и глаголом-связкой ***быть.***  Глагол **задает именной части Т.п.**, а в случае **И.п.** такого **управления нет.**
3. При выборе падежа учитывается **постоянный или временный** характер признака, а также **стиль речи** (разговорный или книжный).
4. По контексту выбираем вариант **с постоянным признаком**:

*Пусть это будет  **ваше мнение.***

**ТЕОРИЯ**

**[Розенталь §179. Формы сказуемого](https://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm)**

Существительное и прилагательное в функции **именной части** составного сказуемого могут стоять как в форме **именительного**, так и в форме т**ворительного падежа**; ср.:

И в семье его Савельич был свой человек (Мельников:Печерский). – И у Ивашиных он был своим человеком (Чехов); День был тусклый, теплый (Шукшин):

Обычно в этих случаях **именительный падеж** существительного указывает на **устойчивый признак предмета**, на постоянно присущую ему **качественную** характеристику, а творительный падеж – **на временный признак.** Ср. у Пушкина: Германн был сын обрусевшего немца. – Бопре в отечестве своем был парикмахером, потом в Пруссии солдатом.

Однако это разграничение **не проводится последовательно,** например: А Давид... был сначала пастух (В. Панова) (употреблена форма именительного падежа, хотя указывается временный признак); Дом, мимо которого бежала Аночка, был городской школой (Федин) (употреблена форма творительного падежа, хотя имеется в виду постоянный признак);

**Имя прилагательное** в составном сказуемом независимо от типа связки (незнаменательные или знаменательные глаголы-связки) обладает **большей свободой** в выборе формы творительного или именительного падежей. Но **творительный падеж** свойствен **книжной речи**, а именительный – **разговорной**.

Я бываю гадкая... (Л.Толстой). – Когда же я бываю любезным! (Тургенев). Мысль Викентия Алексеевича шла примерно теми же ходами, что и прохоровская, ассоциации были тождественными (В. Липатов). – Парень-то был ядреный, в плечах широкий.